# Merging two pandas dataframes with common data

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Consider this data:

```
  INF  CTR  Time 
A  1    8     3
B  5    1     3
C  3    2     3
```

And I have another set of data with the same elements, but different column names:

```
  INF2  CTR2  Time 
A  3    1     3
B  6    4     3
C  1    7     3
```

I need to merge theses data like this:

```
  INF  CTR  INF2  CTR2  Time 
A  1    8     3    1     3
B  5    1     6    4     3
C  3    2     1    7     3
```

How can I do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you want to join on indexes use [.join()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.join.html), otherwise [pd.merge()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html):

```
df1.join(df2[['INF2', 'CTR2']])
```

Merging on indexes looks like this:

```
pd.merge(
    df1, 
    df2[['INF2', 'CTR2']], 
    left_index=True, 
    right_index=True,
)
```

Please also check out this great post on merging in pandas:
[Pandas Merging 101](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53645882/pandas-merging-101)